# Castle Windsor: How to specify different implementations for different properties of the same type

Tags: c#, properties, castle-windsor

say I got this class:

```
public class Consumer
{
  public ISomeInterface A {get; set;}
  public ISomeInterface B {get; set;}
}
```

and two different implementations of `ISomeInterface`:

```
public class Alpha : ISomeInterface {...}
public class Bravo : ISomeInterface {...}
```

how can I tell Windsor to set `Consumer.A` to instances of `Alpha` and `Consumer.B` to instances of `Bravo`?

By the way, `Consumer` (or the corresponding type in my actual code) is not under my control, but comes from an external library.

The documentation for Windsor states how to suppress property injection for specific properties by decorating them with `[DoNotWire]` or suppress property injection in general. It also mentions the possibility to subclass `PropertiesDependenciesModelInspector` - is that the only way to go, for my scenario? Or is there something easier I overlook?

Thanks,

Max

Comment: I do not see how that other question answers mine. They can use different `.DependsOn`` clauses because they got multiple targets - I got the same target class Consumer with multiple properties inside which I want to inject with different implementations.

Comment: Try the following registration:container.Register(
                Component.For<ISomeInterface>().ImplementedBy<Alpha>().Named("Alpha"),
                Component.For<ISomeInterface>().ImplementedBy<Bravo>().Named("Bravo"),
                Component.For<Consumer>()
                    .DependsOn(
                        Dependency.OnComponent("A", "Alpha"),
                        Dependency.OnComponent("B", "Bravo")
                ));